# Sectioning features/paths in d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have several SVG paths that change of fill color and opacity depending on some parameters.

When two parameters are on the same SVG feature I  want to clearly show that in this feature there are these 2 different 'things' (or objects).

I first was thinking on mixing two different colors (if there would be only one parameter, then just one color), but now I see it is not very intuitive.

Maybe it would be more expressive to divide the square (or circle) by the half (in case only 2 params) or by 3,4,5... each section with its corresponding color (user will also  have a legend with each parameter => corresponding colour).

But I have no idea for the moment about how to start implementing this.

Any idea, link or suggestion is appreciated... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a `<path>` for each individual feature, create a group (`<g>`) for each individual feature which can hold an arbitrary number of `<path>` elements, or whatever you need to do to help differentiate between the parameters. Note that any data bound to the `<g>` element is automatically available/bound to its children.